# Coupling Azure AD with existing user accounts in our solution

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, microsoft-identity-platform

I've been following steps from Microsoft Identity Platform documentation, to enable Azure AD authentication on our existing Angular SPA with .Net Core 2.1 API as backend.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-overview

The basics are now working, but I have a question I've not been able to find a good answer for.

In our current system, we have an existing User and Rights model, which I need to keep. Closing in on 2.000 distint userrights we can set, and the User object used widely in our model.

So, I need to couple the Azure AD account to a given User object in our context.

Our existing auth solution has the User identifier as claim in the JWT - and when token is validated in the API I can set the current user context on the request using that claim.

The most obvious solution is to use the "preferred_username" claim in the returned id-token from Azure. So on the API side, after the JWT auth has validated the token, I change the logic in my SetCurrentUserMiddleware, to look up the User based on AzureAD email - and set user context based on that. Snippet from Middleware class

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
  var currentPrincipal = context.User;
  if(currentPrincipal != null)
  {
    if(currentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      if(currentPrincipal.HasClaim((x) => x.Type == "preferred_username"))
      {
        var email = currentPrincipal.FindFirst((x) => x.Type == "preferred_username").Value;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
          CurrentUser = new User { WindowsUserName = email }.FetchOne();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The benefits to me are:

- When an admin in our system creates a new user, it is easy for the admin to find the email associated with the users account, and thus make the coupling.
- The email is already used in the login process at MS - so must be assumed unique.
- The customer will just need to register our applications in Azure App Registration with correct configuration (In Azure and our applications), and then it will work.

Our solution is deployed in various ways. Some clients has it hosted by us, on distinct domain per customer, some has it all in-house on-premise

The question that now arise is, if this is the preferred way, and if this is a secure way of doing it.

Or are there better alternatives for mapping Azure Ad / Identity Platform with a local user database.

I hope someone has some hints, or some good resources to point me to.

Best regards
/Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial mapping can possibly be done with the user principal name/email, but you should store the oid or sub claim of the user instead to map them in the future, as those are immutable.
A user's UPN/email can be changed, so it is not a stable identifier.

The oid claim (aka objectId) is the unique immutable id that is used to identify the user e.g. in Microsoft Graph API.
The sub claim (aka name identifier) is also a unique immutable id, but the value your application gets there is unique to the app, so another app would get a different value here.

Typically I recommend storing the objectId, as that allows you to query for data from MS Graph API if needed.

ID token reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. So we add a field for the oid in our database. When setting up the current user, we lookup using oid - and if I can't find a match, we can lookup using the email, and if found store the oid on that record. And then from that point on, the oid can be used as the unique mapping between Azure AD on our User objects.